# Postgresql select count even if the joining table has empty record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a user table as below

table.users

```
{id:1, name:'USER 1'}
{id:2, name:'USER 2'}
{id:3, name:'USER 3'}
{id:4, name:'USER 4'}
```

The USER 1 sends message to all users with a chat window id is inserted in table.messages

table.messages

```
{id:1,chat_id:1, from_user:1: message:'Hi'}
{id:2,chat_id:1, from_user:1: message:'How are you'}
{id:3,chat_id:1, from_user:1: message:'This is broadcasted'}
```

table.last_read

```
{id:1, last_read_message_id:3, user_id:2, chat_id:1}
{id:2, last_read_message_id:3, user_id:3, chat_id:1}
```

I am using the below query to fetch the unread message by the user , as the table.last_read inserting only when alteast one read ,USER 4 will not have record in table.last_read, the below returns last_read_message_id null in the left join and returns 0 records

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages  m
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT last_read_message_id
        FROM last_read  
        WHERE user_id=4
    ) lr ON m.chat_id=lr.chat_id
    WHERE m.chat_id=1 AND m.id>last_read_message_id
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of the `LEFT JOIN` is negated because you are referencing a field from that table in your `WHERE` clause. It is behaving like an `INNER JOIN` as a result.

To fix this, add the criterion to your `JOIN` specification instead.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN last_read lr
  ON  m.chat_id = lr.chat_id
  AND m.id > lr.last_read_message_id
  AND lr.user_id = 4
WHERE m.chat_id = 1
```

This is the equivalent of yours with the last_read_message_id moved from the `WHERE` to the `JOIN`.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c0b0f/2

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN last_read lr
  ON  m.chat_id = lr.chat_id
  AND m.id > lr.last_read_message_id
  AND lr.user_id = 2
WHERE m.chat_id = 1 will return 3 rows , in that case the messages are already read and should return 0 as count as the USER 2 read all the messages

Comment: Is this now a different question than what you originally asked?